# Can Euclid's lemma be extended to fractions?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know already that Euclid's lemma applies to integers but can it also apply to fractions? And if it does or does not then why?

For example if you have
$\frac{ a × b}{c}$
Where a and b are fractions. C is a prime number. Let us suppose that C is bigger than a or b which means that c does not divide a or b. Does this mean that c also does not divide $a×b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$c=5$ , $a=\frac{10}{3}$, $b=\frac{3}{2}$ is a counterexample.

More general:
$c=p$, $a=\frac{np}{m}$, $b=\frac{m}{q}$ were $q$ is a divisor of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Easy counterexample is $c=5, a=\frac{5}{2}, b=2$.

Clearly $c$ doesn't divide $a$ nor $b$, however

$$\frac{ab}{c} = \frac{\frac{5}{2}\cdot 2}{5} = 1$$

Edit: As OP wanted proper fractions,

$a = \frac{35}{11}$, $b= \frac{11}{7}$, $c=5$

Then
$$ab/c = \frac{\frac{35\cdot 11}{11\cdot 7}}{5} = \frac{5}{5}=1$$

Comment: How is 2 a fraction? That is not the kind of fraction I have in mind.

Comment: @Arthur You are right, I reverted the edits. Clearly you can write an integer as a fraction, but if someone thinks of an example where both numbers are proper fractions (namely in $\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{N}$, I would be happy to see it)

Comment: $c=5$ , $a=\frac{10}{3}$, $b=\frac{3}{2}$ can works?

Comment: @EmilioNovati I think you have gotten it. Please post your answer I will accept it.